# Change organization to upload binary on iTunes Connect using Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode9

I've more than one Team configured on Xcode9, when I try to upload binary to iTunes Connect on Xcode 9, there is no option to change Team and the following error appear: ERROR ITMS-4088

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A solution from Apple Developer Forums:**
1.Archive normally
2.Window -> Organizer -> Select the archive you wish to upload -> Export
3.Open the exported folder to find YourAppName.ipa
4.Select the Xcode menu on the top left (menu bar) -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader
5.Select the appropriate team in the top left dropdown
6.Follow the steps to choose your ipa file
7.Upload

Comment: The team selected in Target/General is correct, but did't make any difference.

Comment: I found someone has same problem, and solved it by using Application Loader. Answer updated.