# Upload Build Using XCode 9

Tags: xcode9

As IOS release its new updates we have IOS-11 now and to support we have Xcode9.

Xcode-9 has changes its upload process of build to i-Tunes and its quite unfamiliar for us to Follow the process.

Recently i need to upload the build but the selection of certificate section is quite confusing.

I have choose my distribution certificates but i it will not allow me to proceed further

Sometimes its says : 'Profile is not manually managed.'
Sometimes its says : Profile is not Appstore certificates.

Please if anyone can guide me How to Upload build using Xcode-9

Thanks.

Comment: Try use Application Loader to upload IPA to AppStore: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46360099/1784529

Answer (score 0):

I think choosing Automatically manage signing, and trying to upload a build using Application Loader will solve you problem.